# Why does python try to use apt for "run of the mill" error

Tags: python-3.4

I get the following in python:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i=9/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init_config()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

From what I have googled it seems python is trying to submit a crash report. What I would like to know is why is it doing this for a normal error?

The same does not happen in python2.

```
lsb_release -a:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because that's how the distro has it set up.

Comment: Is there anyway to change it? Does anyone know why this was changed in python3.4 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I tried uninstalling python3-apport and that fixed the problem.